# Adding VLAN removes earlier virtual IPs in CentOS 6.X

Tags: vlan

I added some virtual IPs to my eth0 interface in CentOS 6.5,

```
ip addr add 192.168.100.2 dev eth0
```

I then simply added a VLAN on eth0.

```
vconfig eth0 10
```

The VLAN was created but it removes any of my added IPs on eth0 (eg. 192.168.100.2).

I didn't face this issue in CentOS 5.X. The eth0 retains IPs.

Comment: I've removed "SOLVED" from the title of this question for two reasons: First, that is not how we indicate a question is resolved here, and second, this question obviously does not have a workable answer yet.

Answer (score 1):

use ip notation for the vlan too - see the archlinux wiki https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/VLAN

```
ip link add link eth0 name eth0.10 type vlan id 10
```

Comment: Thanks, with Google search I came across the same link. Tried but it has the same problem. All other IPs (except the physical IP) disappear.

Comment: order is important - first create the link, then add new addr to the new link: ip addr add  192.168.100.2 dev eth0.10

Comment: The problem I'm facing is with IPs on eth0 which I want to retain. IPs for eth0.10 could be added later without a problem. The IPs however are retained on CentOS 5.4.

Comment: can you post content of /etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-net.rules

Comment: # This file was automatically generated by the /lib/udev/write_net_rules
# program, run by the persistent-net-generator.rules rules file.
#
# You can modify it, as long as you keep each rule on a single
# line, and change only the value of the NAME= key.

# PCI device 0x8086:0x1026 (e1000)
SUBSYSTEM=="net", ACTION=="add", DRIVERS=="?*", ATTR{address}=="00:0e:0c:aa:9b:aa", ATTR{type}=="1", KERNEL=="eth*", NAME="eth0"

# PCI device 0x8086:0x1026 (e1000)
SUBSYSTEM=="net", ACTION=="add", DRIVERS=="?*", ATTR{address}=="00:0e:0c:aa:c0:a8", ATTR{type}=="1", KERNEL=="eth*", NAME="eth1"

Comment: excuse me for the formatting. I'm not able to allow line breaks.

Comment: It is probably an issue on 6.5, it worked fine on older version 6.4.

Answer (score 0):

It is probably an issue with CentOS 6.5. 
It worked fine when tried on CentOS 6.4. The IPs on the interface are retained.